# What's the difference between Vec3b and CV_8UC3 in openCV C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

According to the documentation I found online, CV_8UC3 is 3 channels of 8 bits unsigned int. Vec3b is a vector consist of 3 one-byte big entries. Apparently they are of the same size. What is the difference between the two data type?

To give the question more context, I'm learning openCV and I am trying to "subtract" one image from the other. Below is an example of what I want to do, and this code works:

```
Mat diff(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
for (int r=0; r<100; r++){
    for (int c=0; c<100; c++){
        diff.at<Vec3b>(r,c)[0] = imageA.at<Vec3b>(r,c)[0] - imageB.at<Vec3b>(r,c)[0];
    }
}
```

For the above code, if I construct `diff` with `diff(100, 100, Vec3b);`, Xcode would complain "expected '(' for function style cast" which I believe is a syntax error. I took a look at the comments of the constructor:

```
@param type Array type. Use CV_8UC1, ..., CV_64FC4 to create 1-4 channel matrices, or
CV_8UC(n), ..., CV_64FC(n) to create multi-channel (up to CV_CN_MAX channels) matrices.
```

So it seems that it doesn't take in Vec3b. 
However, if I use `CV_8UC3` with `.at` function like `diff.at<CV_8UC3>(r,c)` with or without index brackets, Xcode would complain "No matching member function to call 'at' ". I didn't find any comments for `at`.

That doesn't make sense to me. Why can the data in the object not be accessed by the same datatype when it is created (CV_8UC3)? Are the two datatypes really different? (Because supposedly different datatypes should have different sizes, shouldn't they?)

FYI: I'm using opencv 3.4.1_5, C++, xcode, mac.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `CV_8UC3` is just a number (specifically it's `16`), while `Vec3b` is a struct... They are entirely different things. It's like asking what's the difference between the number 42 and a `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks Miki! So does that mean `CV_8UC3` is just a flag passed to Mat construct to tell which struct is used, whereas the `.at` function doesn't take this flag but takes the actual struct type, which is `Vec3b` ?